# undefined method `configure' for MyGem:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, rubygems

**Context of the Problem**

- `gem 'leanpirates-aarrr', '~> 0.1.1', :path => "/src/gem-aarrr"` runs ok
- `rails g` shows the generator `lean_pirates:aarrr:install`
- the initializer is successfully created under `config/initializers/leanpirates_aarrr.rb`
- but the initializer **FAILS** when trying to configure the gem

**The initializer: leanpirates_aarrr.rb**

```
LeanPirates::Aarrr.configure do |config|
  config.api_server     = "http://localhost:3000"
  config.startup_key    = Rails.configuration.leanpirates_aarrr.startup_key
  config.startup_secret = Rails.application.secrets.leanpirates_startup_secret
end
```

**The gem definition file: aarrr.rb**

```
# (...)
module LeanPirates
  module Aarrr
    class << self
      attr_writer :configuration
    end

    def self.configuration
      @configuration ||= LeanPirates::Aarrr::Domain::Configuration.new
    end

    def self.reset
      @configuration = LeanPirates::Aarrr::Domain::Configuration.new
    end

    def self.configure
      yield(configuration)
    end
  end
end
```

**The error**

`/src/app-ebusiness-v3/config/initializers/leanpirates_aarrr.rb:1:in <top (required)>: undefined method 'configure' for LeanPirates::Aarrr:Module (NoMethodError)`

```
/src/app-ebusiness-v3/config/initializers/leanpirates_aarrr.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for LeanPirates::Aarrr:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    (...)
```

This is for the opensource **LeanPirates AARRR** from https://github.com/lean-pirates/gem-aarrr/tree/simplification (branch `simplification`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved**

@tadman guided me in the right direction with his explanation (thanks very much for that), although the problem was bigger than I could initially assess.

The Rails **Autoloader** was having trouble to load my files. **Why? Because I tried to organise them.**

**The problem was**

*Namespacing!* Long ago, when the gem was started, it felt reasonable to move everything into a /lib/gem folder. However, it proved to be the source of the problem.

With the namespacing not matching the folder structure properly, the **Autoloader** was having trouble loading the files, and they were not getting recognised along with the classes of my gem, etc.

**How was the Namespacing sorted?**

When you are doing your gems, make sure that you understand well namespacing. In my case, generating the plugin with the following command line sorted out the problem:

`rails plugin new lean_pirates-aarrr`

This line above created things in the way they should be for the auto-loader to pick up. It's not something we can complain about: Rails follows a lot the "convention over convention" paradigm.

My end structure was the following:
(https://github.com/lean-pirates/gem-aarrr/tree/simplification)

```
- lib/
  -> generators/
    -> lean_pirates/
      -> aarrr/
        -> install/
          -> routines/*.rb
          -> templates/*.rb
          -> *.rb
  -> lean_pirates/
    -> aarrr/
      -> domain/*.rb
      -> helpers/*.rb
      -> *.rb
```

I'd be happier to make /generators and /gem at the root, and I'm sure it would be possible, but I don't really wanna fight the convention, so I'm pretty happy to leave it as is, at least for now.

If you are facing the same problem, fixing the folder structure might help the **Autoloader** to find your files. Change it, or configure it accordingly.

Comment: Good explanation of what it takes to get it working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The Autoloader feature in Rails is very handy, it takes care of a ton of things automagically, but it's also not very smart. If a namespace is already defined it will not load additional files.

It's your obligation as a gem to require any and all support modules or classes that are necessary for your library to work properly.

Here's the problem in `lib/gem/aarrr/version.rb`:

```
module LeanPirates
  module Aarrr
      VERSION = '0.1.1'
  end
end
```

Now `LeanPirates::Aarrr` is already defined so no additional work by the autoloader is required. As such, your `lib/gem/aarrr.rb` is never loaded.

To fix this you need to avoid creating that namespace path. You should also ensure that `require_paths` is set properly in your `.gemspec` file so that `lib/gem` is referenced correctly. Right now you'd have to `require 'gem/aarrr'` which is really confusing and clunky.

I usually set up a plain-old `VERSION` file in the main gem directory that has nothing but the version string. The `gemspec` can read this in on-demand if required with `File.read`, or you can bake it into the `.gemspec` using a rake task. I prefer the latter approach as making a `.gemspec` with tons of arbitrary code in it is always over-complicating things.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I think I got what you said: the setup is preventing the Autoloader to load `lib/gem/aarrr.rb`, but it isn't quite clear to me what you mean by:

(a) `To fix this you need to avoid creating that namespace path.` how would I do it?,

(b)  `I usually set up a plain-old VERSION file in the main gem directory that has nothing but the version string.`, since my version.rb doesn't do much more than that, it only has the version. Can you give a little extra information about those? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally I use [Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) for packaging, it takes care of this for you, baking the version into the `.gemspec` on-demand. There are other packagers that do the same thing. Manually constructing these can be annoying. Whatever you do, you must avoid creating `LeanPirates::Aarrr` so even `LeanPirates::VERSION` would do.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. Although I couldn't understand perfectly/use your directions provided here, they DID pointed me in the right direction. +1 for you for that, and I will answer the outcome.